# Android: on home click, emulator preserves app state while a real phone doesnt?

Tags: android

It appears that when I click "Home" on an emulator and return to the app, the state is preserved.

But this doesn't seem to be the case with my physical phone (T-Mobile Move, 2.2).

Why? How can I make Android preserve the app state after clicking "Home" on the phone so that when the user returns, everything remains intact?

Comment: Are you testing the same screens, same state?

Comment: I meant the screen, yeah. On my emulator, the screen returns to what it was before clicking "Home", but on my real phone it appears like onCreate() gets called again.

Comment: Could you elaborate further? I'm not sure what you mean. I did test it on the same activity (Main).

Comment: How much memory does the emulator get? It's possible that if the activity is too big, the OS kills it on the phone when it goes into the background because the phone is out of memory. The emulator may have lots more memory and hence, not kill the app to reclaim it.

Comment: That may be the case as I'm getting the "Low memory warning" on my real phone. I'll try and free some memory up.

Comment: Indeed, it was a memory issue! Write up your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: This is the @ChuckNorris himself. You do not tell him what he does or he will kick you in the head :P. Good catch Chuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much memory does the emulator get? It's possible that if the activity is too big, the OS kills it on the phone when it goes into the background because the phone is out of memory. The emulator may have lots more memory and hence, not kill the app to reclaim it.